# Memory leak when assigning numpy.argpartition() to list element multiple times

Tags: python, numpy, memory-leaks, mutable

I am having trouble understanding a memory leak in my code. I guess that my mistake has to do with numpy arrays being mutable, since it can be solved using `.copy()`.

I don't understand why this happens, though. Here is a minimal example of the code with memory leak, that uses around 1600MB in memory:

```py
import numpy as np
import sys

k_neighbours = 5
np.random.seed(42)
data = np.random.rand(10000)

for _ in range(3):
    closest_neighbours = [
        # get indices of k closest neighbours
        np.argpartition(
            np.abs(data-point),
            k_neighbours
        )[:k_neighbours]
        for point in data
    ]

print('\nsize:',sys.getsizeof(closest_neighbours))
print('first 3 entries:',closest_neighbours[:3])
```

And here is the same code, but with an added `.copy()`. This seems to solve the problem, the program is about 80 MB in memory, as I would expect.

```py
for _ in range(3):
    closest_neighbours = [
        # get indices of k closest neighbours
        np.argpartition(
            np.abs(data-point),
            k_neighbours
        )[:k_neighbours].copy()
        for point in data
    ]

print('\nsize:',sys.getsizeof(closest_neighbours))
print('first 3 entries:',closest_neighbours[:3])
```

The final result is the same for both:

```
size: 87624
first 3 entries: [
    array([   0, 3612, 2390,  348, 3976]),
    array([   1, 6326, 2638, 9978,  412]),
    array([5823, 5866,    2, 1003, 9307])
]
```

as expected.

I would have thought that `np.argpartition()` creates a *new* object, and therefore, I don't understand why `copy()` solves the memory problem. Even if that's not the case and `np.argpartition()` somehow changes the `data` object itself, why does that result in a memory leak?

Comment: Think it's the slicing `[:k_neighbours]` that's responsible for leaks.

Comment: I think I don't understand why, though. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Think it's because the slicing references to an intermediate array. Sorry, I don't have all the details, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be boiled down to this example:

```py
import numpy as np

array = np.empty(10000)
view = array[:5]
copy = array[:5].copy()
```

Here the memory usage of the `view` object will also be much higher than the memory usage of the `copy` object.

**Explanation**

As described in the [NumPy manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing), "NumPy slicing creates a view instead of a copy". Therefore the underlying memory of the original array "will not be released until all arrays derived from it are garbage-collected."

When slicing a large array the Numpy docs also suggests using `copy()`:
"Care must be taken when extracting a small portion from a large array ... in such cases an explicit copy() is recommended."

**Measuring the memory usage**

The reason [`sys.getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) returned the same value in both of your examples is because, "only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to." In your examples you called `sys.getsizeof` on a list object, which therefore returns the size of the list and does not account for the size of NumPy arrays within it.

For example, `sys.getsizeof([None for _ in data])` will also return `87624`.

**Memory usage of numpy arrays**

To get the size of the `data` array you can call `sys.getsizeof` with a `data` as its argument:

```py
sys.getsizeof(data)
```

Now, to get the size of all arrays in your `closest_neighbours` list, you might try something like this:

```py
sum(sys.getsizeof(x) for x in closest_neighbours)
```

Be aware that this will not work if the list contains any `views`. As stated in the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) the `sys.getsize` "will return correct results [for built-in objects], but this does not have to hold true for third-party extensions as it is implementation specific." And in case of NumPy views `view.__sizeof__()` will return 96.

Comment: Thank you! So using .copy() causes the large array to be garbage-collected after slicing, since it is not referenced by any object anymore. Without using copy(), it remains referenced by the slice, so that the entire array is kept in memory, correct?